# Libreoffice Calc Saving TSV as CSV without asking

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Create a tab-separated file saved as test.txt.
Open in text editor and save:

```
1   2   3   4
This    is  a   test
```

(Those are tabs)

1. Open it with Libreoffice Calc
2. Click "Save"
3. Libreoffice asks "Are you sure you don't want to save as ODS?" or like
4. Click "Use text csv format"

Open test.txt file in Text editor:

```
1,2,3,4
This,is,a,test
```

This is UNACCEPTABLE behavior that I would like to know how to stop. The file was a TSV, I did not specify to change it into a CSV. Libreoffice should KEEP my original format setting.

Note: Previous versions did (I'm pretty sure) since this is part of a workflow I've been using for years (since before the OO / LO schism)

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- LO: 5.1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open with Calc, does it ask you stuff about the file (like encoding, column separators, text separators)? If it does make sure you uncheck all separators save for tabs.

I often open CSV files with semicolons as separators, unchecking all separators but semicolons, and Calc never turned them into commas.

Comment: Well I'll be... That appears to work. I'm still not happy that it changes my separator to comma just because I have both tab and comma checked when I open it... So I'm still hoping there's a "solution" rather than a behavior modification.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask Calc to save a file [as CSV as defined in RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), it will do so. If you want Calc to use a different format, you'll have to tell Calc explicitly to do so. The way to do this is using the ***CSV filter settings***. To access the filter settings, tick the checkbox in the "Save" dialog (it's active only after selecting a format that requires a filter):

[image]

Now, after confirming to save the file in a different format than ods, you can set the csv field separator:

[image]

See also the [docs on loading / saving CSV files](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_CSV_Files).